# Fresh ASP.NET Core API returns empty JSON objects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a .NET Core Web API project to test it out.

My problem is, that the API returns an empty JSON object, when I request the endpoint, which is located at "/api/cars/123" for instance. This happens no matter what kind of object I put in, unless it's any primitive datatype, or an array thereof. The response is always:

```
{}
```

The configuration of the application is completely default, on a fresh Visual Studio 2017 installation.

I have the following classes:

**Car.cs**

```
namespace Ex6.Entities
{
    public class Car
    {
        private int Id { get; set; }
        private string Make { get; set; }
        private string Model { get; set; }

        public Car(int Id, string Make, string Model)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.Make = Make;
            this.Model = Model;
        }
    }
}
```

**CarsController.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Ex6.Entities;

namespace Ex6.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CarsController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public JsonResult GetCar(int id)
        {
            return Json(new Car(1, "Toyota", "Aygo" ));
        }

    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, updating the question again. It made no difference though :S

Comment: Yes, and if I try mapping the Car object to a variable before returning it, I can see in the debugger that it's constructed properly. :)

Comment: Adding the autogenerated files now

Comment: I access it through the API, by sending a GET request to "/api/cars/123" for example.

Comment: Do i need a JSON serializer, or will ASP.NET core take care of it automatically?

Comment: Related post - [Why asp.net core sending empty object as response?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59714992/465053)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

In order for the JsonSerializer to be able to see and serialize your properties, they need to be public:

```
public int Id { get; private set; } //the setters can be private
public string Make { get; set; }
public string Model { get; set; }
```

Comment: I encountered the same problem when converting a legacy WCF to WebAPI. However, the problem I had was a result class that had all fields and no properties. I added a getter and setter to all the fields to convert them to auto-properties everything worked.

Comment: Couldn't find this in documentation. Wish it was easier to find this answer...

Comment: Can JsonSerializer be configured to report these kind of issues?

Comment: Not the issue with the OP, but it's worth noting that they also can't be fields, even if public.

Comment: Incredible.  Coming from Newtonsoft where fields worked, this had me stumped until I found this answer.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, Text.JSON doesn't serialize public fields as well, so they need to be properties. This solved the similar issue for me

Answer (score -1):

Try this by adding configure

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

....AddNewtonsoftJson() this should solve the issue.