# Why asp.net core sending empty object as response?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

When I debug the code in VS, the cities list, which I am returning have 3 objects in it along with the properties. When I call this endpoint I am receiving a response of 3 list items of empty objects.

How to resolve this issue?

## Model Class:

```
public class City
{
    public string CityName;
    public string AssociatedCities; 
    public string Province;
    public int Status;

    public City(string cityName, string associatedCities, string province, int status)
    {
        this.CityName = cityName;
        this.AssociatedCities = associatedCities;
        this.Province = province;
        this.Status = status;
    }
}
```

## Endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("cities")]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<City>> GetCities()
{
    return Ok(Cities);
}
```

This is how I am calling the endpoint

```
getCities() {
  this.http.get<City[]>('/api/wizard/cities')
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log(result);
    this.cities = result;
  }, error => console.error('Something went wrong : ' + error));
}
```

The response I get:
[image: Reponse Result]

The response that is needed:

```
[
  {
    "SearchCity": "Toronto",
    "AssociatedCities": "Ajax, Whitby, Toronto, Mississauga, Brampton",
    "Province": "ON",
    "Status": 1
  },
  {
    "SearchCity": "Vancouver",
    "AssociatedCities": "Vancouver, Vancouver City",
    "Province": "BC",
    "Status": 1
  }
]
```

I have tried this already: [Fresh ASP.NET Core API returns empty JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318390/fresh-asp-net-core-api-returns-empty-json-objects)

Comment: Please add your definition of `Cities`.

Comment: do you have `public City()` constructor? Please add default constructor and try one more time `public City() {}`

Comment: Thanks will update it now.

Comment: The JSON serialiser doesn't support _fields_ - use _properties_. i.e. `public string CityName { get; set; }` etc.

Comment: Thanks @KirkLarkin worked for me.  Newbie here that' why made the mistake. Thanks again.

Comment: As a heads up, the dotnet team and community are working on adding support to serialize fields. [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/876) is the relevant dotnet/runtime issue and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/36240) the relevant dotnet/corefx issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the fact that all your action does is return `Cities`, which presumably is a property or field defined on your controller, I'm going to take a shot in the dark and assume that you're setting that in another request and expecting it to still be there in this request. That's not how it works. The controller is instantiated and disposed with each request, so anything set to it during the lifetime of a request will not survive. As a result, `Cities` has nothing in this request, so you get an empty response.

If you need a list of cities in the action, then you should query those *in that action*. Also, for what it's worth, System.Text.Json does not currently support serializing fields, as others have mentioned in the comments, but you may still use JSON.NET instead, which does. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#jsonnet-support

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time. The cities were setting up in the same request. As suggested by @krik Larkin and you as well i simply changed fields to properties like public string cityname to  public string cityname {get; set;}  and it worked.

Answer (score 20):

`System.Text.Json` currently does not support serialization/deserialization of fields and non-parameter-less, non-default constructors.

Your example model uses both **fields** and a **non-default constructor**. If you need to use a custom constructor for some reason, you would need to implement your own `JsonConverter<T>` to support that. This doc might be helpful for that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#deserialize-to-immutable-classes-and-structs

Only **public properties** with public getters/setters are supported along with the **default, parameter-less constructor** (what is referred to as [Plain_old_CLR_object (POCO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_CLR_object)). Note: If you are only serializing (i.e. writing), the setters generally don't have to be public.

[Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) are different from fields (and contain getters/setters).

Here is the fix:

```
public class City
{
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public string AssociatedCities { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I just added this in my ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs (I am using Dot Net 5.0)

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: It works for me. I've to add package:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

Comment: I am using .net 6, same issue, and there is no Startup.cs, also no ConfigureServices method in the entire REST server project...

Comment: @JayImerman or for anyone having this issue .... get this nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson (choose your ,net supported version)
andservices.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(); in your program file