# Swagger missing data when retrieving records from ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using swagger to test my ASP.NET Core Web API project controller's method. Swagger sees all my end points and lets me call them without issue. Swagger returns the number of records expected either one or many and all the field names are correct, but all are missing the data.

All my controllers are returning `JObjects` or in case of `GetAll()` - `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject>.

The `Agency` table contains two records. Here is what Swagger displays:

```
[
  {
    "agency_name": [],
    "agency_url": [],
    "agency_timezone": [],
    "agency_lang": [],
    "agency_phone": [],
    "agencyID": [],
    "Divisions": []
  },
  {
    "agency_name": [],
    "agency_url": [],
    "agency_timezone": [],
    "agency_lang": [],
    "agency_phone": [],
    "agencyID": [],
    "Divisions": []
  }
]
```

It doesn't matter if I return 1 record or many.

I have set a break point at the last "return" line of the controller method, and it shows that data is being returned. Yet it is not showing in the Swagger UI.

I feel like I have left out an obvious step. Perhaps in the `Program` class?

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Erick.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Swagger out of the box doesn't like JObjects.  I found a similar question back here [Why asp.net core sending empty object as response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59714992/why-asp-net-core-sending-empty-object-as-response)

The solution was provided by [farman-ameer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9576348/abdul-samad)
and others.

I'm not sure if it applies to all .NET versions.  But for .NET 6.0 it worked.
You need to reference Nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson in your project. I didn't have to add a using reference to this assembly in the program class. Then in your "ConfigureServices" method of your Program class add/modify this line "services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();"